# Will Adal work with Azure ADFS mode

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adfs, adal

I currently use authentication to azure AD using ADAL code as follows.

```
 var userCred = new UserPasswordCredential(username, context.Password);
 AuthenticationResult authResult = await 
authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(""https://graph.windows.net/"", 
 clientId, userCred);
```

This code works well. but I may have a situation now, where Azure AD will implement ADFS and connects to On Premise AD for authentication.

My Question is, will the above code of Adal work with the changed infrastructure? and passing username and password(valid with on premise AD) suffice?

*Currently I do not have setup in place, hence this is more to see the feasibility .

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Azure AD will implement ADFS". Do you mean a federated tenant using AAD Connect?

AAD Connect syncs AD users to Azure AD and also syncs their passwords.

You will now have two kinds of users:

- Those already there
- Those synced

It should still work because the users are in Azure AD.

If you have ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) you can use ADAL direct.